# nodejs execute string variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm using sails.js.
1) I'd like to print 'dolphin' from object matchingCol.

```
var matchingCol = {
    'card': {
        'add': {
            'voo': 'dolphin'
        }
    }
};

module.exports = {

    methodA: function (req, res) {
        var a = 'card';
        var b = 'add';
        var c = 'voo';
        return res.send(matchingCol.a.b.c);
    },
};
```

2) If I'd like to declare object, and want to parse 'foo' to key, how can I do?

```
var key = 'foo';
var params = {
    key: 'anything'
};
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, if you have a variable that represents the property name of an object, you can use square brackets to access it:

```
 return res.send(matchingCol[a][b][c]);
```

You can also use square brackets for assignment:

```
 var key = 'foo';
 var params = {};
 params[key] = 'anything';
```

Comment: thanks, you save my time a lot, can you please answer my second question (2)).

Comment: I've expanded my answer to cover the second part of your question.